# lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following lines of code :

```
#define PORT 9987
```

and

```
char *ptr = (char *)&PORT;
```

This seems to work in my server code. But as I wrote it in my client code, it gives this error message :

```
lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means you can't take the address of a number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in your server code either - something must be different there.

Comment: @CarlNorum heres my server code. http://pastie.org/7951356
Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Oh i got the error. I have written :

    #define PORT "9987"

in my server. But I dont know how it fixes it.

Comment: String literals are lvalues, integer literals aren't.  In this case, both are wrong, though.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta which compiler are you using on the server?

Comment: It didn't work anywhere. It's wrong. You are mistaken.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta: the quotes make it a string literal -- so you're allocating a static string and getting the address of that.

Comment: Guys, you might not like his attitude, but closing the question is *definitely* an error. Plenty of folks get confused about this.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm sorry I didnt mean to offend anyone.

Comment: @Lazylabs Im using GNU C.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks! That clears it out for me. :)

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta You did nothing wrong. I'm just trying to guess why there are close votes on this. Please don't forget to upvote all the good answers and click the checkmark for the best one.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

C preprocessor is at play here. After the code is preprocessed, this how it looks like.

```
char *ptr = (char *)&9987;
```

address of (`&`) operator can be applied to a variable and not a literal.

Answer (score 8):

The preprocessor macros have no memory and at compile time the macro is replaced with the value. So actualy thing happening here is `char *ptr = (char *)&9987`;, which is not possible.

Comment: I think it may not be a #define.

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta `9987` is not lvalue -[read here](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#ref)

Comment: yes constants are not lvalue. But for & operation lvalue is required.