# lvalue required as unary '&' operand in C Program

Tags: c, arrays

Could someone explain the reason behind error in last line of this C Code? I am trying to print address of a single dimension array element.
Array a is defined as:

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

printf("%p",a+1); //No Error 

printf("%p",&a); //No Error 

printf("%p",&(a+1)); //lvalue required as unary '&' operand Error
```

Comment: what is `a`? what its data type?

Comment: All of those are wrong. `printf` `%p` takes a `void *`.

Comment: "*`//No Error`*" but a warning, right?

Comment: If the array is `a[...]` then you need `a + 1`. The array `a` decays to a pointer.

Comment: ... or `&a[1]`.

Comment: ... or `&(*(a + 1))`. Urgs ...

Comment: More on rvalue & lvalue here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1

Comment: It might be helpful if you showed how `a` is defined; or better: provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @OmG    'a' is an single dimension integer array. why is printing &a not giving an error while &(a+1) gives an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727370/lvalue-required-as-unary-operand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` is an array and having storage address, but `a + 1` is an operation without saving to a variable, and `&(a + 1)` means the address of that operation and it does not mean anything in `C`. Hence, this `&` is found as a bitwise operator by the compiler, so you are getting this error.

Comment: @alk thanks. it's updated.

Comment: But the error message says: `lvalue required as unary '&' operand`, while the bitwise `&` operator is a _binary_ operator. The problem is that `a + 1` is not an lvalue, and you can't take the address of an rvalue.